# QPaint draw lines with offset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qpainter

I would like to draw some lines with `QPainter`, then move the start `(x1,y1)` coordinates of lines to `centerpoint` and some other lines which want to offset from center. Those lines should behave programmatically based on value of ellipse or other values. I have tried myself different ways to come around it but does not work.

To `QRect` can utilize codes such as

```
moveCenter, moveTopLeft, etc...
```

But for `Qline` there are not such methods. According to **PyQt doc**, a line can be drawn by this:

```
QLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
QLine(const QPoint &p1, const QPoint &p2)
```

Maybe this line should be used in order to offset it. But no knowlegde to do it.

`translated(const QPoint &offset)`

On another hand would like to draw some texts and offset them in similar way as `Qline`.

Look at figures below to see what is that I exactly want to do?

**Visualisation**

What I have achieved so far.

[image]

What I want to achieve.

[image]

**The code:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Foo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 100, 700, 600))        
        self.paint = Paint()
        self.sizeHint()
        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.lay.addWidget(self.paint)
        self.setLayout(self.lay)

class Paint(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Paint, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Base)     
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        xl = self.rect().center().x()
        yl = self.rect().center().y()

        self.e = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QSize(250, 250))
        self.l = QtCore.QLine(QtCore.QPoint(xl, yl) , QtCore.QPoint(self.width(), self.height()/2))



    def paintEvent(self, event):
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush( QtCore.Qt.darkCyan, QtCore.Qt.Dense7Pattern)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.e.moveCenter(self.rect().center())

        painter.drawEllipse(self.e)
        painter.drawLine(self.l)
#        painter.drawText('D')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Foo()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**The Update issue:**

I have updated the code, I manage to draw what I want. But having another challenge. You could see on figure below.

**When code runs and displays**

[image]

**When Widget minimizes or maximizes, some lines disappears?**

[image]

**The Update code:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Foo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 100, 700, 600))        
        self.paint = Paint()
        self.sizeHint()
        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.lay.addWidget(self.paint)
        self.setLayout(self.lay)

class Paint(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Paint, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Base)     
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)


        self.e = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QSize(250, 250))
        self.l1 = QtCore.QLine(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QPoint(200, 0))
        self.l2 = QtCore.QLine(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QPoint(0, -200))

        self.vl = QtCore.QLine(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QPoint(0, -125))
        delta = QtCore.QPoint(20, 0)
        self.hl = QtCore.QLine(-delta, self.e.topRight() + delta)
        self.al = QtCore.QLine(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QPoint(-20, -20))
        self.a2 = QtCore.QLine(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QPoint(-20, 20))
        self.a3 = QtCore.QLine(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QPoint(20, 20))
        self.a4 = QtCore.QLine(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QPoint(-20, 20))
        self._factor = 1.0

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush( QtCore.Qt.darkCyan, QtCore.Qt.Dense7Pattern)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.e.moveCenter(self.rect().center())
        self.l1.translate(self.rect().center() - self.l1.p1())
        self.l2.translate(self.rect().center() - self.l2.p1())

        self.al.translate(self.l1.p2())
        self.a2.translate(self.l1.p2())

        painter.translate(self.rect().center())
        painter.scale(self._factor, self._factor)
        painter.translate(-self.rect().center())

        painter.drawEllipse(self.e)
        painter.drawLine(self.l1)
        painter.drawLine(self.l2)

        fnt = painter.font() 
        fnt.setPointSize(20) 
        painter.setFont(fnt) 
        h = QtGui.QFontMetrics(painter.font()).height() 
        p = QtCore.QPoint(self.rect().center().x(), self.e.top() - 3*h) 
        u = QtCore.QPoint(self.e.right() + 3*h, self.rect().center().y()) 
        painter.drawText(p, "y")
        painter.drawText(u, "x")

        r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(self.e.x(), self.e.bottom()), QtCore.QSize(self.e.width(), h)) 
        painter.drawText(r, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, "D = 350mm")
        offset = QtCore.QPoint(0, 1.5*h)

        self.vl.translate(self.e.bottomLeft() - self.vl.p1() + offset)
        painter.drawLine(self.vl)
        self.vl.translate(self.e.width(), 0)
        painter.drawLine(self.vl)
        self.hl.translate(self.e.bottomLeft() +  offset - QtCore.QPoint(0, 0.4*h))

        self.a3.translate(self.l2.p2())
        self.a4.translate(self.l2.p2())

        painter.drawLine(self.hl)
        painter.drawLine(self.al)
        painter.drawLine(self.a2)
        painter.drawLine(self.a3)
        painter.drawLine(self.a4)       


    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        self._factor *= 1.01**(event.angleDelta().y()/15.0)
        self.update()
        super(Paint, self).wheelEvent(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Foo()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I do not know why it behaves like this? any comment or help I appreciate much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt does not know what size the widget will have at the beginning so `self.rect()` will have any size, for example in my test `self.rect()` in `__init__` returns `PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 480)` but in `paintEvent()` it returns `PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 678, 578)` so that's why the calculation is incorrect.

the solution is to move the line with `translate()`(do not use `translated()` because this creates a new QLine and that's what I do not want)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Foo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 100, 700, 600))        
        self.paint = Paint()
        self.sizeHint()
        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.lay.addWidget(self.paint)
        self.setLayout(self.lay)

class Paint(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Paint, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Base)     
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        self.e = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QSize(250, 250))
        self.l1 = QtCore.QLine(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QPoint(200, 0))
        self.l2 = QtCore.QLine(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QPoint(0, -200))

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush( QtCore.Qt.darkCyan, QtCore.Qt.Dense7Pattern)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.e.moveCenter(self.rect().center())
        self.l1.translate(self.rect().center() - self.l1.p1())
        self.l2.translate(self.rect().center() - self.l2.p1())
        painter.drawEllipse(self.e)
        painter.drawLine(self.l1)
        painter.drawLine(self.l2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Foo()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

**Update:**

```
class Paint(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Paint, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Base)     
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        self.e = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QSize(250, 250))
        self.l1 = QtCore.QLine(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QPoint(200, 0))
        self.l2 = QtCore.QLine(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QPoint(0, -200))

        self.vl = QtCore.QLine(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QPoint(0, -125))
        delta = QtCore.QPoint(20, 0)
        self.hl = QtCore.QLine(-delta, self.e.topRight() + delta)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush( QtCore.Qt.darkCyan, QtCore.Qt.Dense7Pattern)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.e.moveCenter(self.rect().center())
        self.l1.translate(self.rect().center() - self.l1.p1())
        self.l2.translate(self.rect().center() - self.l2.p1())

        painter.drawEllipse(self.e)
        painter.drawLine(self.l1)
        painter.drawLine(self.l2)

        fnt = painter.font() 
        fnt.setPointSize(25) 
        painter.setFont(fnt) 
        h = QtGui.QFontMetrics(painter.font()).height() 
        p = QtCore.QPoint(self.rect().center().x(), self.e.bottom() + 0.8*h)

        r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(self.e.x(), self.e.bottom()), QtCore.QSize(self.e.width(), h)) 
        painter.drawText(r, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, "D")
        offset = QtCore.QPoint(0, 1.5*h)

        self.vl.translate(self.e.bottomLeft() - self.vl.p1() + offset)
        painter.drawLine(self.vl)
        self.vl.translate(self.e.width(), 0)
        painter.drawLine(self.vl)
        self.hl.translate(self.e.bottomLeft() +  offset - QtCore.QPoint(0, 20))
        painter.drawLine(self.hl)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works and you are right. But could I use the same method for text?

Comment: @ZarKha use `fnt = painter.font()
        fnt.setPointSize(25)
        painter.setFont(fnt)
        h = QtGui.QFontMetrics(painter.font()).height()
        p = QtCore.QPoint(self.rect().center().x(), self.e.bottom() + h) 
        painter.drawText(p, "D")`

Comment: I do not think so, that there is possibility to draw arrow at p2() of lines. is arrow predefined i Qt or it should be done by other ways

Comment: @ZarKha you have to create it, it's a simple triangle

Comment: I manage to draw the dimensionlines. this code for left vertical line according to `self.rect().center()`. `self.l3.translate(QtCore.QPoint(self.rect().center().x()-250/2 , self.e.left()))` is there a better or quick way to go to these coordinates.

Comment: try with: `self.l3.translate(self.l2.p2())`

Comment: Not really working? draw in center. I want to offset to left or right side of circel.

Comment: @ZarKha you must do it after `self.l2.translate(...)`

Comment: Still does not work. I have added after `self.l2.translate(...)`.

Comment: @ZarKha well without a [mcve] I can not help you since I'm assuming certain things and it probably is not true

Comment: @ZarKha What do you want to draw? What are l3 and l4?

Comment: I want to draw 3 dimensionlines one on the left side of text **D** and on the right side of text **D**, then one beneath text **D**. I believe this is right way to do it, but seems do not behave like this.

Comment: @ZarKha I see, I assumed you were drawing the triangle that you pointed out yesterday

Comment: You have to be clear, at no point did you point me out on those lines in your comments I assumed that we were talking about the arrowhead and you are using my code, I do not know if *your steps* are correct.

Comment: I want clearly to do dimensionlines right now, l3 and l4 is for that purpose. No I did not, I thought that I should add `self.l3.translate(self.l2.p2())` to obtain dimensionlines. Regarding arrowheads no I have not started at them.

Comment: Thanks, now it works, much better, but one thing, when the widget expands or minimizes last line disappears, I am talking about following code line:      `self.hl.translate(self.e.bottomLeft() +  offset - QtCore.QPoint(0, 20))`
 `painter.drawLine(self.hl)`

Comment: Do you have any idea, why it behaves like this? the code is updated!

Comment: @ZarKha I have not reviewed your problem, but the normal thing in these cases is to establish a minimum size of the widgets so this type of problems is avoided, surely the solution is geometric but I do not want to dig deeper because the problem has become more geometric than programming Do not you think?

Comment: Well, you are right at establish minimum ( sizefix) size of the widgets would solve it. In my case size of widgets would expand and resize. I would look at it and dig deeper into geometry to solve it. I really like to program with PyQT5, but what I hate most, is Qpainter and serialization. Thanks so much for help :)